# StandaloneFileBrowser for MacOSX

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build for MacOS IL2CPP for [FileBrowser plugin](https://github.com/rubenwe/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser) but can't get it to work. Works fine on macos and standalone mono and editor.

I get this in failed il2cpp log file:
System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly is referenced by user code, but is not supported on StandaloneOSX platform. Various failures might follow.

How do I use the StandaloneFileBrowser file in subfolder StandaloneFileBrowser.Bundle/Contents/MacOS ?

Dlls Ookii.Dialogs, StandaloneFileBrowser, System.Windows.Forms have the option to include Editor, Standalone or WSAPlayer but not MacOS?

Also I notice the plugin folder for this asset is inside the StandaloneFileBrowser directory (StandaloneFileBrowser/plugins), should I move all/part of these dlls or this plugin folder into the Assets/plugin path?

Sorry, I find this quite confusing, please help

Thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: I replied to your GitHub issue.

Comment: yup! Thanks a bunch @LexLi ! if you post reply here I can set it as the answer, cheers !!

Comment: You can write your own answer and summarize what you have learned.

Answer (score 0):

@Lex Li was very kind to solve this, thanks again !!! macOS now requires 64 bit apps, but Mono WinForms is 32 bit only, so this file browser no longer runs on Mac.
Alternative some other cross platform [UI framework](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea)

Found this for [pay](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/file-browser-pro-98713) too